# How to filter the child object from Parent model in Django Rest API?

Tags: python, django

```
class Tyre(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    product_type = models.CharField(max_length=128)


class TyrePrices(models.Model):
    tyre = models.ForeignKey(Tyre, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    discount = models.IntegerField()
    description = models.TextField(max_length=256)
    discount_price = models.IntegerField()
    stock = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

This is model, and the requirement is want to filter the tyre according to tyre price range(which is at the second model).

How can I do this?

Comment: What have you done so far? So we can take you from there.

Answer (score 1):

```
Tyre.objects.filter(tyreprices__price__gte=x,tyreprices__price__lte=y)
```

If you want a range. Otherwise drop one or the other. Or adjust for exclusions.

Answer (score 1):

When you have a relation, Django create automaticaly a reverse relation ([doc here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) :

```
tyre = models.ForeignKey(Tyre, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

can be noted this way :

```
tyre = models.ForeignKey(Tyre, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="tyreprices")
```

For your query just do :

```
Tyre.objects.filter(tyreprices__price__range=(x,y))
```

Comment: Thank you, I got Tyre model object, but i am not able to get the price associated that tyre. Please help.
Thanks in advance.